Reducing Variance with Regularization in LOOCV for Small Datasets
I have a small dataset and I am considering using Leave-One-Out Cross-Validation (LOOCV) to evaluate my model. I understand that cross-validation, in general, is a method to assess a model's performance on unseen data.
However, I am concerned about the bias-variance tradeoff. Specifically, with LOOCV, there is a risk of having low bias but high variance. To mitigate this, I am thinking of using regularization models (L1, L2, or Elastic Net) to introduce some bias and reduce variance(at the same time when using the loocv...).
Could you provide any tips or best practices for implementing this approach? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.


with LOOCV, there is a risk of having low bias but high variance

I think you misunderstood what this variance is about: it is the variance uncertainty of the LOO-estimator, compared to other estimators of generalization error.
This statement is not about the variance of the model itself (instability). LOOCV like similar techniques for generalization error estimation treat the model as black box, whose (variance and bias) properties exist and (some of them) are to be measured rather than influenced.

Still, this variance (instability) of the surrogate models does enter the variance of the LOOCV estimates as one of several relevant variance components for the LOOCV result's uncertainty. More specifically, repeated k-fold or leave-n-out CV allow to measure it, while LOOCV is subject to it, but cannot separate it from variance uncertainty stemming from the finite number of tested cases.
